# a code that understands a number is prime or normal at Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and write this code for recognizing a number is prime or not.
I wrote a code that works in JavaScript and visual Basic, but didn't work in Python and its error is: **TypeError:a float is required**.
my code:

```
import math
a = raw_input("Enter a number:")
k = 0
i = 1
s = math.sqrt(a)
while i <= s:
    if a % i == 0:
        k += 1
    i += 1
if k == 2:
    print "prime num"
else:
    print "normal num"
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more issues in your code: `while` loop is only up to square root of a given number, but you print `prime num` for k==2. In this code there will be only one divisor, and it is 1.

What is more, you can start from `i=2`, so there will be 0 divisors for a prime number. After that, last issue is that 1 is not a prime number. So the code looks like that:

```
import math
a = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
k = 0
i = 2
s = math.sqrt(a)
#print(s)
while i <= s:
    if a % i == 0:
        k += 1
    i += 1
#print(k)
if k == 0 and a > 1:
    print "prime num"
else:
    print "normal num"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just convert the user input to `int`.
`a = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))`

What's wrong is that you were trying to find the square root of a value of type `string` (text).

Answer (score -1):

first check the version of your python, if you using python3 then take only 
`a=input("enter number")`
raw_input works for python2